# iOS Apps and data survivability

Tags: ios

Sandboxed applications have certain document folders where they can keep data such as plists and sqlite files. Those folders are resistant to upgrade, meaning -- when you upgrade the app from the app store, the data will not get reset.

However, when you remove the app, all local data is removed? isn't it? is there a way to persist it beyond application deletion? so that if you re-install, you just get your old data back?

Comment: Yes, you can persist some minor data using the Keychain, but that's about it aside from storing the data on your server.

Comment: It is not obvious to me that all an apps data is removed when an app is removed. It might be, but i haven't seen it documented anywhere. Have you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store data externally in iCloud, Dropbox, or another online service.

The nice thing about this is that not only will the data survive deletion-and-reinstall, but it will also survive the user replacing the device, upgrading to a new device, sharing data between devices, etc.

Comment: thanks for your response, yes, I know about the external options - was asking about device local stored data.